# Designing a DRF-React App with Configurable Social and LDAP Authentication

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, ldap, google-oauth

I'm working on a DRF + React and aiming to implement various authentication methods, including social authentication (Google, Facebook, GitHub) and LDAP server integration. I want the flexibility to configure these authentication methods according to my requirements. Specifically, I would like to remove or add social authentication providers as needed.

The key requirements are:

- Social authentication (Google, Facebook, GitHub).
- LDAP server authentication.
- Configurability to easily add/remove authentication providers.
- JWT-based session login authentication.

I want to ensure that the solution is maintainable, scalable, and provides the desired flexibility in configuring authentication methods.

Any examples or references to existing projects with similar setups would be greatly appreciated.

```
This is what I am currently doing, I have configured a google auth which has a client based flow
- Users click on sign in with google from frontend
- Google returns a one time code
- Then frontend send this code to backend and backend validates this with google and returns user details in form of jwt token
- jwt token is stored on local storage, and this token is used to call each and every API as an authorisation header, if token is expired/invalid backend sends 403 forbidden and user is logged out.
```

Thanks in advance!